# How to config MacVim to support command/control key + arrow key to switch between windows?

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

here is the config file of my vimrc, but it doesn't work on my mac ,

```
"ctrl + left
imap <silent> <C-left> <esc><C-W><left>
vmap <silent> <C-left> <esc><C-W><left>
nmap <silent> <C-left> <C-W><left>
"ctrl + right
imap <silent> <C-right> <esc><C-W><right>
vmap <silent> <C-right> <esc><C-W><right>
nmap <silent> <C-right> <C-W><right>
"ctrl + up
imap <silent> <C-up> <esc><C-W><up>
vmap <silent> <C-up> <esc><C-W><up>
nmap <silent> <C-up> <C-W><up>
"ctrl + down
imap <silent> <C-down> <esc><C-W><down>
vmap <silent> <C-down> <esc><C-W><down>
nmap <silent> <C-down> <C-W><down>
```

so how to config it ? which character should I use instead of "C" ?
thanks

Comment: This works fine for me (using MacVim as well).

Comment: well,ctrl+arrow is space switching on my Mac,and option+arrow and command+arrow is not work

Comment: For command arrow you should use `D` (e.g. <D-down>), as described by Kevin Ballard, below. For Option you use `M`. What is probably happening here is that the OS is intercepting the Control arrow before MacVim can see it. Go to system preferences > expose and spaces > spaces and disable the the Control + Arrow keys to switch spaces.

Comment: thanks guys, the problem was solved , i just put that configs from .vimrc to .gvimrc, is that means such config only work in the GUI mode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you want `<D-down>` for Cmd-Down (and -right/-up-/-left for the others). Seems to work in my testing.

Comment: well,ctrl+arrow is space switching on my Mac,and option+arrow and command+arrow is not work